# HTML5 input type show only years

Tags: html, date

Maybe this question already asked but that not solve my problem.

This is my query in input box i want to show only years like this

[image]

Thanks in advance

> Note: Already this qustions asked but it not solve my issue

Comment: Try [select and show year only](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Year-Picker-Text-Input/). And guide is [here](https://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Year-Picker-Text-Input.html)

Comment: Should I write my answer to Answer form, then you will mark it to be a correct answer?

Comment: @NgocNam: Yeah sure

Comment: Thank you, I added the answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try [select and show year only](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Year-Picker-Text-Input/). And [guide is here](https://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Year-Picker-Text-Input.html)

Answer (score 5):

How to Resolve input year only `<input date="year">`

You can use this snippet.

**PHP Version:**

```
  <select class="form-control" name="startyear">
   <?php
   for ($year = (int)date('Y'); 1900 <= $year; $year--): ?>
     <option value="<?=$year;?>"><?=$year;?></option>
   <?php endfor; ?>
  </select>
```

**JavaScript Version:**

```
    <select name="yearpicker" id="yearpicker"></select>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    let startYear = 1800;
    let endYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    for (i = endYear; i > startYear; i--)
    {
      $('#yearpicker').append($('<option />').val(i).html(i));
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: PHP version works great but somehow the js version doesn't output anything.

Comment: @ailia you have to include [jquery](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js) to make it work

Answer (score 1):

I would like to make a small correction to Rhalp's answer for efficiency sake. Don't initialize the object 219 times. In general it's much less work on the browser engine if you get the member before you loop over it.

```html
    <select name="yearpicker" id="yearpicker"></select>

    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    let startYear = 1800;
    let endYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    for (i = endYear; i > startYear; i--)
    {
      $('#yearpicker').append($('<option />').val(i).html(i));
    }
    </script>
```